# Jquery equal Heights

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know what am I doing wrong.. but I have 3 columns where I want to apply equal heights

here is my html

```
    <div id="wrapper">
  <div class="LeftBG"></div>
  <div id="MainBlock">THIS IS A TEST</div>
  <div class="RightBG"></div>
    <!-- END CONTENT BLOCK -->
  </div>
```

and here is my function and just doesn't work....

```
    var highestCol = Math.max(
    $('.LeftBG').height(),
    $('.RightBG').height());
$('#MainBlock').height(highestCol);
```

To see what I am doing [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gw8b8/17/)

Comment: It seems to work. Just apply the height to all three elements.

Comment: can you please tell me exactly where and which to apply to which element.. I am not really a Jquery dude I just found this script

Comment: It would be good to learn. jquery uses css style selectors: http://htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/selectors/

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to this to set all three blocks to the same height:

```
var highestCol = Math.max(
    $('.RightBG').height(),
    $('.LeftBG').height());
$('#MainBlock, .RightBG, .LeftBG').height(highestCol);
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Rv4fr/

Answer (score 1):

What you did fixes the middle column, now apply it to the other classes as well...

```
var highestCol = Math.max(
    $('.RightBG').height(),
    $('.LeftBG').height());
$('#MainBlock').height(highestCol);
$('.RightBG').height(highestCol);
$('.LeftBG').height(highestCol);
```